# ng-click not fire in ng-switch and ng-inclide

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I write a small app using angularjs an typescript. Now i want to fire a click within a directive witch is build with ng-switch and ng-include. The problem is that the ng-click not fire, if i print out a value every thing work fine.

Controller:

```
export class MenuController {

        private _scope: any;
        private _location: any;

        static $inject = ['$scope', '$location'];
        constructor($scope, $location) {
            this._scope = $scope;
            this._location = $location;

            if(!window.localStorage.getItem("token")) {
                $location.path("/home");
            }
            this.logout = this.logout;
        }

        public logout(): void {
            window.localStorage.removeItem("token");
            this._location.path("/confirmRegistration");
        }

        public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
            return localStorage.getItem("token") != undefined;
        };

    }
    angular
        .module('app.menu')
        .controller('MenuController', MenuController);
```

Module:

```
angular.module('app.menu', [
        'app.core'
    ]).directive("osMenu", function() {
        return {
          restrict: "E",
          controller: "MenuController as vm",
          templateUrl: "js/menu/menu.html"
        };
    });
```

Html with switch and include:

```
<ul id="nav">
        <div ng-switch on="vm.isAuthenticated()">
            <div ng-switch-when="true">
                <div ng-include="'js/menu/membermenu.html'"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="false">
                <div ng-include="'js/menu/nonmembermenu.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

Template with click:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="vm.logout()">Logout {{vm.isAuthenticated()}}</a>
```

The {{vm.isAuthenticated()}} will print out correctly but the vm.logout() is not fireing.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the tipp with batarang, basarat.

The scopes look so:
[scope with batarang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfnHK.png)

but how can i access my instance of HomeController? $parent.$parent.vm.logout() is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the ng-click not fire, if i print out a value every thing work fine.

Because you have an `ng-switch` with `ng-include` along with `vm` in there, suspect either controller inheritance has got you off guard or `vm` is not the `vm` you think it is (not the right controller).

## Debugging

Use developer tools with batarang to check the scope on the html element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with batarang. I updated my question with a screenshot from scopes. But i'm still unable to call the function in scope(1) from scope(7),